# Change default redirect after login in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in laravel. i'm using udemy videos to learn laravel. I wanna to change  default redirect after login. 
I change route to

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'],function (){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

and in `Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

but when I login again I redirect to `/home` instead of `/admin/home`.
I clear cache but it doesn't work true again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the redirection to be only unauthorized, then just write

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'guest'],function (){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
 });
```

and if you want to redirect to 'admin/home' after login you mast change in

> LoginController

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/admin/home';
```

Comment: No, i want to redirect after authorization for admin.

Comment: Tnx, `protected $redirectTo = '/admin/home';` solved my problem.